# Can't debug windows phone app on real device

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-8, device, nokia

I'm trying to debug my WP8 App on a nokia 520. All works fine on the emulator but once i pick "device" as target, I still get the same error :

```
Error   1   Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Downloading package 'FF6XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXF32'': 
SmartDeviceException - Referenced package not found
    XXXXX
```

I am using VS2013 Update RC2.
The device is registered.

Would someone know how to fix it ?

Comment: Did you find an answer?